# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can only check the position for partitions assigned to this consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

For the following code I used

```
 KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
 consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(TOPIC));
 TopicPartition partition = new TopicPartition(TOPIC, 0);
 System.out.println(consumer.position(partition));
```

I received the error like the "You can only check the position for partitions assigned to this consumer.", what's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 4):

When partitions are automatically assigned a call to `poll` after `subscribe` will trigger a rebalance and partition assignment. You are missing that `poll` call.

Comment: Can you give an example for this answer with props and code included?

Comment: Here's a link to a maintained example in the Kafka repo: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Consumer.java